# how to confirm Security risk alert in C# web browser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am developing a application with a WebBrowser control that login to site, but it give security alert:

> Revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available.
>   Do you want to proceed?

I want to that its automatically confirm this alert using code.

I find many question on this issue but they are not useful in my case.

Comment: ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score -1):

Use Fiddler tool to identify Security related issues.

Comment: I don't understand what you tell, give me hints